# 'config' (string expected, got table)

Tags: connection, wifi, nodemcu

My code and result:

```
> file.open("wifitest.lua","w+");

> w = file.writeline

> w([==[wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)]==]);

> w([==[]==]);

> w([==[station_cfg={};]==]);

> w([==[station_cfg.ssid="netia9000";]==]);

> w([==[station_cfg.pwd="mywifipassword";]==]);

> w([==[print(station_cfg.ssid)]==]);

> w([==[wifi.sta.config{station_cfg}]==]);

> w([==[wifi.sta.connect()]==]);

> w([==[status_of_wifi = wifi.sta.status()]==]);

> file.close();

> dofile("wifitest.lua");

netia9000

wifitest.lua:7: bad argument #1 to 'config' (string expected, got table)

>
```

Line 7 is the `wifi.sta.config{station_cfg}` statement. I could not find an explanation for the error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: What NodeMCU firmware version do you use?

Comment: Are you using curly braces to call a method (wifi.sta.config()) ? 

Answer (score 0):

you've got old version of NodeMCU firmware.

https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/flash/ (Note that this tool was created by the initial developers of the NodeMCU firmware. It hasn't seen updates since September 2015 and is not maintained by the current NodeMCU firmware team. Be careful to not accidentally flash the very old default firmware the tool is shipped with.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCoMU.png)

Create one more in https://nodemcu-build.com/ (with parameters what you need)
Download nodemcu-flasher https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher
Set up parameters you need.
In config window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCoMU.png)
Choose your set up bin file. Then flash it
After that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qchHL.png) choose right field and choose esp_init_data_default.bin in nodemcu-flasher-master\Resources\Binaries

This is the way of update firmware.